# Is it possible to embed a Getty image as a featured image in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

It is great that Getty Images have made lots of their images free to use on our websites.
But does anyone know a way to include them as a featured image within a WordPress Page or Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at this time without paying Getty for the privilege, or violating copyright and Getty's terms of use.

If you pay Getty (starts around $300 monthly) you can upload their images into your Media Library and use them as you please on your site.

With Getty's new free embeds (iframe-based) there is no way to use the image as your featured image without taking a screenshot and separately attaching the resulting image to your post, which violates Getty's copyright and terms of use.

Comment: it is also illegal to embed the image on your page, go "View Source", find the image, save it to your disk, delete the embed code then upload the image as your own. Very illegal.

Comment: It's not illegal to embed. It's free too(for non-commercial websites). https://www.gettyimages.in/resources/embed

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is allowed and it is also free(If you are running a non commercial website).

Here is the link with more details

https://www.gettyimages.in/resources/embed